# Is there way to edit dll with external tool which web application on windows server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, decompiling

I have use one tool like dnSpy for editing dll classes and methods like charm. However my requirement for edit dll files located on my live server which is windows server 2008. Is there any tool available that gives this service?

Comment: Is there anyone here

Comment: dnSpy can edit any executable.  The services are executables that automatically get started by the operating system.  To access an executable on a remote machine you need admin privileges on both local and remote machines.

Comment: I just want lower version of dnspy that don't need framework 4.7, because windows server 2008 never work with .net 4.7 framework.

Comment: Either use the compile option and build as framework 4.0, or publish application so you update the windows dlls on 2008 server to work with framework 4.7.  Since you are using server 2008 the application should be 32 bit not 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would not edit anything on a live server, but if you have no other alternative, use .Net Reflector. With this tool you can break down a dll and edit and re-compile it.